# Scrapy - too much timeouts (more than half)

Tags: python, web-scraping, timeout, scrapy

I have one generic Spider class which is being instantiated with different lists of urls (different domains).

So for `example.com`, there is one spider instance, for `amazon.com` another.

The `GenericSpider` has set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to 0.5 s to prevent being banned or overload someone.

Every spider has in average 5 urls (sometimes 50, sometimes 1 url)

I can see in log that there is a lot of Timeout errors. Is it possible that there is a problem with spiders settings? I can see hundreds of such errors in log. More that half of requests ends with GIVE UP retries.

EDIT: When I lower the number of Spiders, there is allmost no timeout (not a 50 % of requests, instead 0.5 %)

I download only html so there should be no problem to download it in 15 seconds.

In log, there is hundreds of these:

```
2017-03-31 11:08:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying ... User timeout caused connection failure.
2017-03-31 11:08:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET ...> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting ... took longer than 15 seconds..
```

This is my Spider:

```
class GenericSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    download_timeout = 15
    name = 'will_be_overriden'
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 10,
                       'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':0.5}
    def __init__(self, occs_occurence_scanning_id_map_dict):
        super(GenericScraper,self).__init__()
        occs = occs_occurence_scanning_id_map_dict[0]
        self.occurence_scanning_id_map_dict = occs_occurence_scanning_id_map_dict[1]
        self.name = occs[0].site.name
        self.occs = occs
        self.xpath = self.occs[0].site.xpaths.first().xpath

    def start_requests(self):
        for occ in self.occs:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=occ.url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        successlog.debug('GOT RESPONSE')
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        text_raw = hxs.select(self.xpath+'/text()')

        # DO SOME STUFF IN DATABASE
```

And this is how I run the crawler:

```
def run_spiders():
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    ...

    ua = UserAgent()

    process = CrawlerProcess({'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': 0,
                              "EXTENSIONS": {
                                  'scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': None
                              },
                              "LOG_FILE":'scrapylog.log',
                              "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS":10,
                              "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY":False,
                              "USER_AGENT":ua.chrome,
                              })
    for s in Site.objects.all():
        occs = s.occurences.all()
        if occs:
            occs_occurence_scanning_id_map_dict = (occs, occurence_scanning_id_map_dict)
            process.crawl(occurence_spider.GenericScraper, occs_occurence_scanning_id_map_dict)

    process.start()
```

Comment: If you're crawling something like amazon (which is quite notorious for crawler bans) you most likely are just banned, in otherwords - amazon gets your requests but knows that you are most likely a bot and doesn't respond. Could you describe your timeout patterns more? do they happen randomly? towards the end of the crawl?

Comment: @Granitosaurus No, there is no problem with such thing like banning I think. And the timeouts aren't a problem of one domain. It looks indipendent on domain. I think yes, they happen randomly. Can't it be a problem with my resources?

Comment: @Granitosaurus I tried scrapy fetch url on some of these urls and they work without problems when requested.

Comment: I tried to lower the number of spiders and the number of timeouts decreased to almost zero (from 50% to cca 0.5%)

Comment: "I tried to lower the number of spiders" What do you mean by this? currently running on domain or in total on a machine?

Comment: There is only one spider instance for one domain. If you take a look at the loop: for s in Site..:  - for every site there is another instance. I need to scrape urls for all sites but when I lowered the number of Sites (so I lowered the number of spider instances), the timeouts allmost disappeared.

Comment: you can try increasing the twisted reactor's threadpool: `REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 20`; [as described in scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html#increase-twisted-io-thread-pool-maximum-size)

Comment: Tried set RTM to 20 but it didn't help. Only thing which helps is to lower the number of spider instances. But I noticed, that when there is so much timeouts, this error is being raised at the beginning of crawling - multiple times  - Unhandled error in Deferred: